# How to insert timeline card in new user account for first time

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I've followed the Glass [quick start](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/python) guide for Glass for Python.

I'm able to run the server locally and can insert timeline cards to my account using the Admin Panel in Quick Starter. So far so good. But how the flow would look like for a new user? I'm creating a glassware similar to weather updates. In Quick starter, I had to trigger the "post" thru a "form" element. How does it work when someone installs Glassware from store. What triggers that person to get "very first" timeline card. I'm quite confused here. Any useful information will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user turns on your Glassware in MyGlass, they will be redirected to your auth URL and taken through an OAuth flow (just as would happen if you visit that URL manually without going through MyGlass when you're developing). After they go through that authorization, you can perform any post-auth tasks that you need, such as inserting contacts or timeline items.

The relevant code in the Python Quick Start can be found in the [`_perform_post_auth_tasks`](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-python/blob/master/oauth/handler.py#L98) method of the OAuth request handler, which is called at the end of the `get` request before redirecting to the Glassware's main page.